# Remixd Windows 10 - Absolute Path

Tags: remix, windows

Cannot find the right Absolute Path For Remixd on Windows 10.

I have tried both

```
remixd -s C:/MyProjects/SmartContracts --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org
remixd -s C:\MyProjects\SmartContracts --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org
```

In Both cases the remixd is running:

```
[WARN] Symbolic links are not forwarded to Remix IDE
```

But there are no Local folders when opening Remix in Browser

Comment: Another reason it might not be working on Windows is if you are using Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Use wsl2, run remixd like `remixd -s /mnt/d/projects/xxxx --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org`   solves my problem.

Comment: If anyone has problems running node in WSL, follow these instructions https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl before installing remixd.

Answer (score 0):

I have just verified sync on Windows 10 is working as expected for remidx v0.6.2.

```shell
PS C:\Users\Bing.Bai\ethereum\v2-core> remixd -s C:\Users\Bing.Bai\ethereum\v2-core --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org
(node:17196) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'C:\Users\Bing.Bai\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\@remixproject\plugin-ws\package.json' of 'src/index.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:17196) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'C:\Users\Bing.Bai\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\@remixproject\plugin-utils\package.json' of 'src/index.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
(node:17196) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'C:\Users\Bing.Bai\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\@remixproject\plugin\package.json' of 'src/index.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author        
(node:17196) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'C:\Users\Bing.Bai\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\@remixproject\plugin-api\package.json' of 'src/index.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author    
(node:17196) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'C:\Users\Bing.Bai\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\@remixproject\plugin-utils\package.json' of 'src/index.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author  
(node:17196) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'C:\Users\Bing.Bai\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\@remixproject\plugin\package.json' of 'src/index.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author        
[INFO] you are using the latest version 0.6.2
[WARN] You may now only use IDE at https://remix.ethereum.org to connect to that instance
[WARN] Any application that runs on your computer can potentially read from and write to all files in the directory.
[WARN] Symbolic links are not forwarded to Remix IDE

[INFO] Mon Jun 20 2022 13:34:11 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time) remixd is listening on 127.0.0.1:65520
[INFO] Mon Jun 20 2022 13:34:11 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time) slither is listening on 127.0.0.1:65523
setup notifications for C:\Users\Bing.Bai\ethereum\v2-core
```

I'm using PowerShell 7, but any PowerShell version should be fine.

As long as you don't create symlinks, below message means nothing to you.

> [WARN] Symbolic links are not forwarded to Remix IDE